# Loop through Web Elements and Click each link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi my code works My goal is to loop through each element in the table and and click the element so i can go to the next page basically I want to do this

```
1 click element form drop down
2 //code some stuff
3 Go back 
4 click next element from drop down 
5 code some stuff and etc
```

My code:

```
List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.id("companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane"));
     for ( WebElement client: CCTable) { 
         System.out.println("\n"+client.getText().substring(0, 20)+"\n");
        client.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    }
```

[image]

My problem is that its finding and printing out the text in my **console in eclipse ** but it is not clicking on the link or each link.

I am trying to follow the suggestions here https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/how-to-iterate-over-a-collection-of-items-in-selenium-webdriver but no success any help would be appreciated.

If I am doing something wrong please help me. Any help would be appreciated

---

PP_OBJ_CycleData.CCdropdown(driver).click();

```
    List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane table tbody tr[id*=companyIdBarCompListGrid_] td span div a"));
        // inner 4 loop 
        for ( WebElement ccode: CCTable) { 

             System.out.println("\n"+ccode.getText().substring(0, 20)+"\n");
             System.out.println("Number of links: " + CCTable.size());
             Thread.sleep(3000);

             ccode.click();



Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='companyIDBarContentPane']//span"));

            }// End Inner 4 loop



    PP_OBJ_CycleData.ReturnToSupport(driver);
```

Also this is in eclipse console:

[image]

Seems that the get text is not getting the other company code name. and it not looping through again after it clicks the first name and i click i get
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

Comment: Is there an error message you are receiving when it fails to click on the second link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working loop:

```
    String selector = "div#companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane table tbody tr[id*=companyIdBarCompListGrid_] td span div a";
    int links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector)).size();
    System.out.println("Number of links: " + links);

    for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {
        List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
        WebElement client = CCTable.get(i);
        System.out.println("\n"+client.getText().substring(0, 20)+"\n");
        client.click();

        // Things happen here

    }
```

Comment: This worked I can now follow what you did pic it apart practice coding it with other variations... thank you . I know i have come along way but i have so much more to learn.. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

## The problem is you're identifying the wrong thing

The ID points to the DIV. And there is just one DIV; nothing to iterate. And while the DIV is clickable, clicking the DIV does nothing.

Instead, you need to find the A tags. This can be very difficult in a table; and all the IDs aren't really helping.

Basically you want something to the effect of:

```
List<WebElement> CCTable = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#companyIdBarCompListGrid_rows_scrollpane table tbody tr[id*=companyIdBarCompListGrid_] td span div a");
```

You may have to play with it. You can add this line right after the List declaration:

```
System.out.println("Number of links: " + CCTable.size());
```

When it matches your expectations, you've found the right findElements string.

Comment: THIS WORDED THANKS!

Comment: Having another issue it is not looping back to click the drop down code is above

Comment: Stack trace is :org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Any additional help is appreciated

Comment: @Jonathan, based on your original post: When you leave the page and come back, the WebElement is no longer linked. The mixed up way to accomplish what you're trying is: (1) Get the list so you know how many links you have (2) Start a loop with the count of the links (3) **INSIDE** the loop, get the list again (different variable) (4) Using the second variable as the link to click (5) Repeat the loop. Basically, you need to re-read in the links every time you come to the page so that they are not "stale". But you need to read the list in once so you know how many time to iterate the loop.

Comment: Question some of these  clients  have like 4 company codes associated with them so would I have to do the same thing thing with them? Basically I have like 300 Clients and everyone one has 2 to 4 company codes.

Comment: @MivaScott..Thank you for your help so far.. is it possibke to give me an example of what you said I needed to do above. Creating this type of solution is different for me... visually seeing it is better