# Selenium how to click over elements stored in a list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get all elements by partial link text then after that click on each of them and from the following page get some info.
My idea was I should click on each link then back to the previous page then repeat the process for the other links. I saw this post
[Loop through Web Elements and Click each link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161689/loop-through-web-elements-and-click-each-link)

which is in java but any way I dont know why it did not back to the previous page after clicking.

I received the error that says"

*selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)*

here is the code:

```
 links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Preisvergleich")
    for i in range(len(links)):
        tmp = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Preisvergleich")
        if link[i].is_displayed():
            print(f"---------------- inside tmp {i} -------------------------")
            print(tmp[i])
            print(f"---------------- inside  Links {i} -------------------------")
            print(links[i])
            #tmp[i].click()
            links[i].click()

            html = driver.page_source
            response_obj = Selector(text=html)
                        
            des = response_obj.xpath("//p[@class='sh-ds__desc']/span/span/text()").get()
            name = response_obj.xpath("//*[@id='sg-product__pdp-container']/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/text()").get()
            tr_rows = response_obj.xpath("//table[@id='sh-osd__online-sellers-grid']/tbody/tr")
            
            for tr in tr_rows:
                result = result.append({             
                    'ean': EAN,
                    'name': name,
                    'price': remove_characters(tr.xpath("//div[@class='sh-osd__content']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").get()),
                    'shipping': remove_characters(tr.xpath("//div[@class='sh-osd__content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()").get()),
                    'endPrice': remove_characters(tr.xpath("//div[@class='sh-osd__content']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()").get()),
                    'seller': tr.xpath(".//td[1]/div/a/span[1]/text()").get(),
                    'desc': des}, ignore_index = True)
        
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

here you see the reason of the error. After that I defined tmp list and the problem is solved. I was wondering is there any cleaner idea to handle this problem?

*---------------- inside tmp 0 -------------------------

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ef98a66d3e2730b7d181a3f49ac9ed74", element="7632fd07-c1b5-4caf-a4d1-ef8e6334eb4b")>

---------------- inside  Links 0 -------------------------

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ef98a66d3e2730b7d181a3f49ac9ed74", element="7632fd07-c1b5-4caf-a4d1-ef8e6334eb4b")>

---------------- inside tmp 1 -------------------------

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ef98a66d3e2730b7d181a3f49ac9ed74", element="aa17ed78-30b6-42f0-8ae3-432dd7c51788")>

---------------- inside  Links 1 -------------------------

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ef98a66d3e2730b7d181a3f49ac9ed74", element="3d5efb32-2079-4e30-824b-7ca530ab9572")>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stale elements are not clickable. It means that you have navigated to another page. If you want to click all those link again, you can go back to that page and reload the list. Another way is to use driver.get for the the URL's (the link you want to click)

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/navget
https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/waitstateless